# Some Ajax Call are not working with selenium and chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am practicing automated testing skills using Selenium and chrome driver. I am trying to perform the button click on this site https://www.jobbank.gc.ca/jobsearch/jobposting/38741568;jsessionid=7DAF93202517CA09595E49A121ECFCB0.jobsearch74?source=searchresults

I noticed that the AJAX call rarely succeeds after clicking the button (programmatically or by mouse click). But when I try it on regular chrome the Ajax call is always able to complete.

[image]

Is there a config in Selenium to fix this?

BTW I am using Python, ChromeDriver, and Selenium

Below is my code to perform Click. Even I manually click the button directly from the browser(launched by selenium) the button rarely to work as expected. But it works perfectly on ordinary chrome browser.

```
 while looper == 1:
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter >= 300:
        looper = 0
    driver.find_element(By.ID,'applynowbutton').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
    checkHowToApplyDiv = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "howtoapply"})
    if len(checkHowToApplyDiv) > 0: 
        looper = 0
```

i added a while loop to attempt click the button.

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error and thus provide you some way around to solve it. 


https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're not able to perform click on the button with id `applynowbutton` programmatically or by mouse click, right?

Comment: i was able to perform click programmatically, it was able to trigger the event on click but I dont see any ajax response even i do manual click. I think the site has a anti-bot.

Comment: I am to solve it by adding this chrome_options.add_argument( '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solve by adding this `chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() chrome_options.add_argument( '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled' )` I think the site has security with bots

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).